# c# login form with Mysql error

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to create register and login form with Mysql workbench. the register is work,  but there is a error showed

> connection must be valid and open

when clicked login button.  Did I miss something? Thank you

```
   private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((txtPassword.Text != "") && (txtUsername.Text != "")) {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Database=databse;Port = 3306; User ID = root; Password = password123");
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM databse.register WHERE USERNAME = @UserName And PASSWORD = @PassWord";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", this.txtUsername.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", this.txtPassword.Text);

            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    //go to next page - homepage
                    setname = txtUsername.Text;

                    this.Hide();
                    Home home = new Home();
                    home.Show();
                }
                if(dr.HasRows == false)
                {
                    Llog.Text = "Wrong! ";
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter username and password");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You never assigned the connection you created to the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM databse.register WHERE USERNAME = @UserName And PASSWORD = @PassWord", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", this.txtUsername.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", this.txtPassword.Text);
```

You need to set the `MySqlConnection` used by this instance of the `MySqlCommand`.

or in this way

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;    
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM databse.register WHERE USERNAME = @UserName And PASSWORD = @PassWord";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", this.txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassWord", this.txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: I don't know why someone gave downvote, but I used the way that you gave is worked!!! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 4):

You must set the connection of the command. Example:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
```